# ASP.NET, asynchronous, when to use it?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

I'm somewhat vague about when to use asynchronous operations in ASP.NET. I understand, whenever I make a call to external web services such as calling Twitter APIs and what not, I should be using asynchronous operations so the CLR threads could be freed and service other requests, make sense.

I read an excellent blog once mentioned that if your operation is using CPU efficiently, then you shouldn't do asynchronous operation because it has a context switch penalty, however, if you are doing a long operation and waits a lot, then it's worth to do the context switch.

What about a page that use ajax call to a local web service which in turn makes a database operations (takes around 3 seconds), returns JSON and then the page itself using JQuery, renders it for another second for a total of 4 seconds?

What about a traditional webform, from page_load makes the same database operation call (3 seconds) and then take another 3 seconds to render? For instance, a big forum post with 1000 comments?

My general impression is that shouldn't IIS be designed such that EVERY operation is asynchronous by default in the background such that all operation is non-blocking without the context switch penalty? Is that the idea of node.js? and If you do have static pages, no wait operations, only then should you specifically write a synchronous page? Basically the reverse of what is happening now?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The only benefit of asynchronous requests is that it frees up worker threads. So you only notice it if you run out of worker threads. By default, there are 100 threads per CPU. So you won't notice the performance improvement unless you have more than 100 requests per 4 seconds per CPU.

The drawback of asynchronous requests is that it makes your code harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: It's also worth nothing that AJAX does not use multiple threads. JavaScript is strictly singlethreaded.

Comment: Hello Sjoerd and James: 

Thanks. Yes, synchronous threads will get queued up in the thread pool much quickly than asynchronous operation calls and this all makes me think that for a big traffic site with most pages having data bound operations, I should be doing everything in asynchronous operations no? 

For small traffic where thread pool never dries up, I will be obviously wasting my time, such as an intranet site. But for "potentially" big site, I think the rule should be doing  asynchronous operations with the trade off of maintain a somewhat harder to read code base correct?

Comment: You should only use asynchronous webforms if you expect a significant performance improvement from it. You can determine whether you are going to run out of threads using the number of users, the duration of each request and the number of running threads on the server.

Comment: James Johnson, that is not correct. Javascript's user thread is single threaded, but it's free to perform I/O in the background, otherwise you wouldn't be able to do any async.